# To CW or not to CW, that's the question

Tags: discussion, support

[Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) recently discovered [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21719/how-we-can-use-noend-only-in-some-places-in-algorithms/21733#21733) to [How we can use [noend] only in some places in algorithms?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21719/how-we-can-use-noend-only-in-some-places-in-algorithms) was posted as Community Wiki (CW). In cases where this might not have been intended (for whatever reason), what would be the appropriate course of action to reverse this?

Here are some suggestions, but since I haven't done this before, I'm not sure whether my options are even valid:

- **Rollback**: Although rollback might be an option, it does not seem to be a possibility in this case by [reviewing the answer edits](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/21733/revisions);
- **Flag for moderator attention**: Flagging it for moderator attention sounds like the most sensible option, yes? However, if considered appropriately flagged, any [Marshal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/108/marshal)-hungry badge gathered might ask whether this would influence the user's flag weight; or
- **Delete and repost**: This would not be viable for questions that have already received any up-/downvotes without loss of reputation, I guess.

I'm sure the same recourse would hold across both questions and answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just flag for moderator attention.

In such a case, where only the author has edited the answer, there's no doubt that removing the wiki status is appropriate, if requested by the author.

However, if there were already further user editing and substantially contributing to the answer, I would suggest we should keep the wiki status.

Similar for questions: if there are no edits by other users and no CW answers yet, the wiki status may be removed. Otherwise it has to be considered carefully by moderators, in case of questions each case can be discussed on the meta site.